# Convert excel form with macro into web app

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet for a specific purpose which is loaded with multiple formulae in many cells. It has a excel form to fill data and run formula to calculate some values. There is another sheet in the workbook which serve as final data store to save data. The form has a submit button which saves the data in data store. I want to get rid of this excel based solution to something more scalable like a web based application which can be made available to multiple users. Also, application data should be easy to manage from backend when required. This web app should run within intranet or if on internet then should be protected by secure authentication like Google authentication. I have looked up on Google and found solutions like converters, caspio etc. I also tried Google form but replicating macros seems difficult. Caspio seems good but seems more suited for simple excel which does not have or have less vba/macro. I also considered building something on javascript expressjs or django but that requires a lot of effort and time. I require a low cost solution which is easy to build and less on maintenance. What options do I have?